# Setting CSS to use 100% of a monitor display

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to use all the available height in displayed in a monitor for a web browser. I have tried to create CSS for html tags to do so.

So that i have text which scrolls down all of the display. My html tag is set to max_height:100% and this picks up the maximum height available. In this tag I have also tried to set it to max-height:100%, but it only picks around a quarter of the height available from the html tag.

In  the body tag I have two further html tags trying to pick up the max-height values unsuccessfully. My CSS is:

```
html{
max-height: 100%;

}

body{
max-height: 100%;
background-color: #000000;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

#container{
max-height: 100%;
margin-top: 72px;
margin-bottom: 72px;
}

#content {
max-height:100%;
clear: left;
padding: 0px 64px;
}
```

How could I resolve this?

Comment: Is this http://jsfiddle.net/382Hp/ what you are looking for or is it something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add 
    **background-size : 100% 100%;** in body